# (leiningen, s3-wagon-private) How to search for dependencies in private S3 repo?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to use the s3-wagon-private plugin.  I have two lein projects:

- X: a library I made for doing some data munging.  Has some 3rd party dependencies.
- Y: a library I made for working with my database, has X and some 3rd party dependencies.

I have the following in my ~/.lein/profiles.clj file:

```
{:repl {:dependencies [[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]]}
 :user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.10.0"]
              [s3-wagon-private "1.2.0"]]
 :signing {:gpg-key "0xabcdef12"}
 :repositories [["private" {:url "s3p://acme/releases/"
                            :username :env
                            :passphrase :env}]]}}
```

When I run `lein deploy private` in project X, everything work just fine and it gets deployed to S3.

When I run `lein deploy private` in project Y, it complains about not being able to find project X.

```
Could not find artifact X:X:jar:0.7.0 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not find artifact X:X:jar:0.7.0 in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

In other words, it is not looking in my private S3 repo to try to find project X.  How do I solve this?

---

UPDATE: 2016-04-25

In a comment, Daniel Compton asked:

> What happens when you run lein deps in project Y? From your error message, it looks like the repository "private" isn't present in project Y.

When I run `lein deps` in project Y, it does **NOT** give any errors:

```
(py3)aj-laptop:red aj$ lein deps
(:repositories detected in user-level profiles! [:user] 
See https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Repeatability)
```

So I added the following to project.clj in project Y.  This made `lein deploy private` work as expected:

```
:repositories [["private" {:url "s3p://acme/releases/"
                           :username :env
                           :passphrase :env}]]
```

So it seems that Project Y is not picking up :repositories from my ~/.lein/profiles.clj file.  But Project X seems to pick it up just fine.

Comment: Lest anyone should think that I didn't do my due diligence on this, I spent several hours on this last night reading through documentation, the master projects.clj file on github, etc. and trying out a number of variations.  No dice.

Comment: You might try https://github.com/pjstadig/lein-maven-s3-wagon

Comment: What happens when you run `lein deps` in project Y? From your error message, it looks like the repository "private" isn't present in project Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `:repositories` were specified in the user `~/.lein/profiles.clj` file. Leiningen [doesn't really like this](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/4a683b85eda2e0662120a12a1f0680e6ebc0c28c/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/project.clj#L623). I suspect there is a latent bug here, perhaps in the interactions between Lein plugins and the dependency resolution system. Because it is generally not recommended to put `:repositories` in your user profile people may not have run into this before.

I think the best solution is probably to add `:repositories` to every file, annoying though that may be.

Comment: Could be a bug.  More likely is that I just don't understand the intricacies involved here.  But yes, I agree, I should just put the private repository information in the individual project.clj files.